# Is the map $\varphi: W \to W$ bijective?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Is the map $\varphi: W \to W$ bijective?

$$(u_1,u_2, \dots, u_m)=(\lambda_1u_1, \lambda_2u_2, \dots, \lambda_m u_m) $$

My understand is this: since $u_1$ is mapped into $\lambda_1 \times u_1$, and so on, then it is injective because one vector on the left hand side matches one vector on the RHS.

Since all the vectors on the LHS get mapped into the RHS, the map is surjective.
Therefore, the map is bijective. Is my understanding correct? Thanks!

Comment: No, it's not correct. Are there hypoτheses on the λs?

Comment: I suppose $W=K^m$? Otherwise it doesn't seem to make sense...

Comment: Your right about the definition of injective, but you should probably show that your map has this property.  Your definition of surjective is backwards.  Surjective means that for every element in W, you need to show that it lives on the RHS for some element on the LHS.  That is, for all $w\in W$, there exists a $v\in W$ for which $\varphi(v)=w$

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:**

> Since all the vectors on the LHS get mapped into the RHS, the map is surjective.

You misunderstand surjectivity. That ‘all the vectors on the LHS get mapped into the RHS’ only means the mapping is defined on the whole of $W$. That $\varphi$ is surjective means that any vector on the right-hand side is attained by $\varphi$.

For injectivity, which means different vectors on the LHS map to different vectors on the RHS, as this is clearly a linear map, it is enough to prove that if a vector maps to the 0 vector, it is necessarily the zero vector.

Comment: Thanks. I think I kind of understand your explanation. Can I say the map is surjective because everything on the RHS can be written as φ(w), w∈W? And also the range is m for both LHS and RHS ?

Comment: First point: that is the argument to use to prove φ is surjective. I don't understand the second point. The range of what? And what does m denote? Let me add that surjectivity/injectivity depend on the values of the  λs.

Comment: If we say W is the vector space of $U_1 ⊕ U_2 ⊕ ... ⊕ U_m$, and  $λs$ are the eigenvalues of $φ$. How can we describe the surjectivity/injectivity? This area is so vague to me. I cannot really connect the surjectivity/injectivity with eigenspace.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessarily true if there isn't any condition on the $\lambda$s .

For example take $W  = R \ ^ 2 $

$f : W \to W $  $\lambda_1 = 0 , \lambda_2 = 1  $

and take $u_1 = (2,1) , u_2=(3,1)$ , so $f(2,1) = (0,1) = f(3,1) $ but $(3,1)\ne (2,1)$

Comment: $(2,1)$ does not equal $(1,1)$ and it's not clear what $f$ should be.

Comment: I am pretty sure your argument is wrong. Because for these lambdas $f(2,1) \ne f(1,1)$

Comment: Yea, it's right now.  The key is that $\lambda=0$ is special.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! If I say λs are eigenvalues of the transformation, does that condition change anything?

Comment: Does 0 could be an eigenvalue?

Comment: @Liad your original post was wrong for three or four reasons.  It should have been deleted.  And editing it so that it is completely different is as good as deleting it.

Comment: @Gaffney and how that contradicts what i said? comment :"you did this wrong, fix or delete", or something like this. what does down voting gives if the post is still there?

Comment: I am not sure if 0 can be an eigenvalue or not.

Comment: I do not sorry. I just googled it.

Comment: 0 could be an eigenvalue- take for example 2X2 matrix with 1 and zero on its diagonal, and 0 elsewhere.

Comment: @Liad  I downvoted AND said what was wrong and actually undownvoted after it was fixed.  The good of the downvoting is that OP doesn't spend time thinking that your original post was correct.